# beautifulsoup get last tag from snippet, if tag exists

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Here's html snippet 1:

```
<td class="firstleft lineupopt-name" style=""><a href="/link/link_url?id=222" title="Donald Trump" target="_blank">Trump, Donald</a>&nbsp;<span style="color:#666;font-size:10px;">B</span> &nbsp;<span style="color:#cc1100;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;">TTT</span></td>
```

Here's html snippet 2:

```
<td class="firstleft lineupopt-name" style=""><a href="/link/link_url2?id=221" title="Hillary Clinton" target="_blank">Clinton, Hillary</a> &nbsp;<span style="color:#cc1100;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;">TTT</span></td>
```

Here's my relevant code:

```
all = cols[1].find_all('span')
for ele in all:
    if (ele is not None):
        ttt = cols[1].span.text
    else:
        ttt = 'none'
```

Issue: my code works in both instances, but for html snippet 2, it grabs content from the first span tag. In both instances, if the tag exists, I'd like to grab content from only the last span tag. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

BS4 now supports `last-child` so a possible approach could be:

```
soup.select('td span:last-child')
```

To get the texts out just iterat the resultset.

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<td class="firstleft lineupopt-name" style=""><a href="/link/link_url?id=222" title="Donald Trump" target="_blank">Trump, Donald</a>&nbsp;<span style="color:#666;font-size:10px;">B</span> &nbsp;<span style="color:#cc1100;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;">TTT</span></td>
<td class="firstleft lineupopt-name" style=""><a href="/link/link_url2?id=221" title="Hillary Clinton" target="_blank">Clinton, Hillary</a> &nbsp;<span style="color:#cc1100;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;">TTT</span></td>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[t.text for t in soup.select('td span:last-child')]
```

#### Output

```
['TTT', 'TTT']
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach would be to get the last element by `-1` index:

```
ttt = all[-1].text if all else 'none'
```

I've also tried to approach it with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), but `BeautifulSoup` does not support `last-child`, `last-of-type` or `nth-last-of-type` and supports only `nth-of-type` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0):

I test it in conda env with bs4 v4.9.1, and now `nth-last-of-type(1)` is OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select only direct children from an already selected element, use the `:scope` tag to reference itself in the selector, so you can now use `>`, `~`, and `+` operators. [Docs](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/differences/#relative-selectors)

```py
selected_element.select_one(":scope > :last-child")
```